# Fill UIView with color based on percentage

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UIView inside the UIView of UIViewController with Height = 149.0 and Width = 123.5.

I am filling this UIView with color, and I am setting the height of the color to be filled based on a response in percentage from a rest url.

How do I fill the entire View with the above mentioned dimensions for 100% and different values.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You mean you want a custom progress bar?

Comment: No I dont want a progress bar. I am able to fill the UIView currently also ,since the height of UIView is 149.0, for value 100 it fills the UIView midway. So I want it to fill 100% for height 149.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill multiple color in your `uiview` then you need to subclass `UIView` and should override it's `drawRect` method something like,

```
 override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {


    var percentage = CGFloat()  //can declare as instance variable or globally which you get from web service and set it's value!!



    percentage = 0.5

    let upperRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height*percentage)

    let lowerRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + (rect.size.height * percentage), rect.size.width, rect.size.height * (1-percentage))

    UIColor.redColor().set()
    UIRectFill(upperRect)
    UIColor.greenColor().set()
    UIRectFill(lowerRect)



}
```

Comment: I am filling only one color

Comment: then set color only one time! this is just demo!! you should manipulate code as per your requirement!!!