# Fill UIImageView With Color Based on Percentage (swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I am trying to mask an image with a color based on a given percentage. I saw the question "[Fill UIView with color based on percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505395/fill-uiview-with-color-based-on-percentage)" but I'm not sure how to apply the same logic to a UIImageView.

Here is the function for how I mask my image (kmBrain = UIImageView):

```
    func maskImageView(color: UIColor, amount: CGFloat) {
    kmBrain.image = kmBrain.image?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
    kmBrain.tintColor = color
    }
```

Note: this is my first question on stack...sorry if it's not clear!

Comment: I think the easiest way is to subclass the UIImageView. Add another UIView to its subview. Change the frame of this UIView base on percentage.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. What do you mean by "masking the image"? Maybe for 50% you want half image, half solid color? Or maybe you want to tint the image, with 100% being solid color and 50% being a red version of the image?

Comment: I'm sorry it's unclear. The image is starts off as being blank, then based on a given percentage, it should fill up with a blue color. EX: If 50% is the given percentage, then 50% of the image should be colored blue.

Thanks for the responses!